# Partial drawing with OpenGL

Tags: opengl, sharpgl

Can we partially redraw the frame in OpenGl?

For Example: If I have both Lines and Polygons in my frame, Polygons does not change ( same dimensions, colour etc) but there is some slight change in Lines. So I want to render only lines again and not polygons.

Is there a way to achieve this?  There will a drastic change in the performance of my application if this is possible.

Comment: If you can render the polygons and lines independently and combine them in a separate step, then yes. Look into "Framebuffer Objects" and "Render To Texture".

Comment: @kloffy I use vertices and color to create lines and polygons. How to do it with that?

Comment: Well, what I meant is more whether your scene is such that the lines are always drawn on top of the polygons or something similar. Otherwise, it may get a bit more complicated, but probably still possible.